# How do I set themes for widgets in windows?

Tags: qooxdoo

with the tutorials on qooxdoo.org I found out how to theme my widgets. This works great for overall styling. 
If I configure "label", all my labels become a yellow textcolor. If I configure "button/label", all labels on my buttons become a red textcolor while every other remains yellow. Good so far.

What's not working is if I try to set a textcolor for labels inside a window:

"window/label", "window/pane/label", "window/widget/label" With none of these keys I can change the style for label-widget inside my window.

What is the correct key to give labels as child-elements inside my window a different style?

Thanks a lot
Ricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [qx.ui.window.Window](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/api/#qx.ui.window.Window) is a container wich implements *RemoteChildrenHandling*. That means, that the chain of child controls stops when it comes to the window content.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can:

- add a *Label* to a *Window* and set the Label appearance directly
- inherit from *Window* (i.e. a custom *Dialog* class of your own), add a content label as a *childControl* of your dialog and adjust the Label color in your theme by using the choosen child control path

The first option would lead to this code:

```js
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("My Title");
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox(10));
win.add(new qx.ui.basic.Label("My content").set({
  appearance: 'custom-label-appearance'
}));
```

If you've just *some* appearances for Label objects and you don't want to add the `appearance` every time, you also could subclass it:

```js
qx.Class.define("my.Label", {
  extend: qx.ui.basic.Label,
  properties: {
    appearance: {
      refine: true,
      init: 'custom-label-appearance'
    }
  }
});

var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("My Title");
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox(10));
win.add(new my.Label("My content"));
```

Here is an example for the second option:

```js
qx.Class.define("my.Dialog", {
  extend: qx.ui.window.Window,

  construct: function(title, label) {
    this.base(arguments, title);
    this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Atom());
    this.getChildControl('my-label').setValue(label);
  },

  members: {
    //overridden
    _createChildControlImpl : function(id)
    {
      var control;

      switch (id)
      {
        case "my-label":
          control = new qx.ui.basic.Label();
          this.add(control);
          break;
      }

      return control || this.base(arguments, id);
    }
  }
});
```

You can then set the appearance path `window/my-label` in this case.

Note that both solutions will not keep you away from setting appearances to all labels that you add to the window.

Comment: Cajus thank you for very much your fast answer. The first option doesn't seem to be appropriate because at the moment I don't have any clue how many labels (or more windows with more labels) there will be. I would prefer your second suggestion because then I only would have one or just a few places where to add changes later on if the appearance would change and clearer code. Do you have a small example with a few lines of code for a better understanding for me?

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed examples. I'd love to upvote your answer but my reputation is still too low :-( 
I tried all of your examples and I think, the inherited Label-class will suit best. I added your window-object and another default-window-object with testlabels to the document. So I tried to give the inherited window-class a different backgroundcolor because I defined "window-pane" in my Decoration-class with a background-image. Image works for every window but the bgcolor not for the inherited.Do I have to refine the appearance-property for the window-pane in my.Dialog also?

Comment: Can you provide a small playground example for that? It's easier to understand what you're trying to do with a few lines of code.

Comment: I couldn't create a tinyUrl because the code was to large. So I copied the code from the playground to codepen and generated a short url there. Please see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JORzVz and copy the code from the JS-field there to the playground to test.

Comment: @Ricky just add a appearance for *custom-window/pane* which returns a style containing *backgroundColor: 'white'*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this works great. :-) One last question: if I now would decide to use another backgroundImage instead of the white backgroundColor to "custom-window/pane" where would I define it? A simple replacement of backgroundColor: 'white' by backgroundImage: '...' doesn't work because Composite (which seems to be the object that a window-pane is) hasn't a property backgroundImage. I think the qooxdoo-manuals should be a little bit more precisely when to define what layout-element where (decoration or appearance). I read it a third time but the penny hasn't dropped yet ;-)

Comment: The background image is set thru a decorator. So you have to define a decoratior including the new background image and assign it in the appearance.